# TYPO3: Add custom set functions in extension controller

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I'm creating an extension for visitors to sign up to the page.
When signing up, it should create a FE user in the backend which is disabled (and will be manually enabled by an admin). So I'll need to set the `disable` field to `1` when creating the FE user.

This is the function inside my controller:

```
/**
 * action create
 *
 * @param \Vendor\FeReg\Domain\Model\Dummy $newDummy
 * @return void
 */
public function createAction(\Vendor\FeReg\Domain\Model\Dummy $newDummy)
{
    // vars
    $title = $newDummy->getTitle();
    $atitle = $newDummy->getAtitle();
    $fname = $newDummy->getFname();
    $lname = $newDummy->getLname();
    $street = $newDummy->getStreet();
    $city = $newDummy->getCity();
    $post = $newDummy->getPost();
    $phone = $newDummy->getPhone();
    $fax = $newDummy->getFax();
    $email = $newDummy->getEmail();
    $org = $newDummy->getOrg();
    $cat = $newDummy->getCat();
    $field = $newDummy->getField();
    $uname = $newDummy->getUname();
    $ppass = $newDummy->getPpass();
    $cpass = $newDummy->getCpass();
    $fulltitle = ($atitle ? $title." ".$atitle : $title);


    $frontendUser = new FrontendUser();

    $frontendUser->setUsername($uname);
    $frontendUser->setPassword($ppass);
    $frontendUser->setFirstname($fname);
    $frontendUser->setLastname($lname);
    $frontendUser->setAddress($street);
    $frontendUser->setTelephone($phone);
    $frontendUser->setFax($fax);
    $frontendUser->setEmail($email);
    $frontendUser->setTitle($fulltitle);
    $frontendUser->setZip($post);
    $frontendUser->setCity($city);
    $frontendUser->setCompany($org);

    $this->frontendUserRepository->add($frontendUser);

    // $this->dummyRepository->add($newDummy);
    // $this->addFlashMessage($title, '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR);

    $this->redirect('new');
}
```

To make this work I'm also loading the `$frontendUserRepository`.
I need something like `$frontendUser->setDisable(1)`.

Environment: TYPO3 7.6.8 / PHP 5.6.24 / mysqlnd 5.0.11

Comment: No time for a real answer, so just a comment: Build your own `FrontendUser` object which inherits from the extbase one. Add field `disabled` (or however it's called, check TCA or the DB) to it, with getters and setters. Then register it as subclass in your TypoScript configuration. After that, you should be able to use it just like you use the normal FE user object. There are examples in the Internet how to do this.

Comment: a FE user can be set hidden or Deleted, not disabled.   look at the model of a FE user.

Comment: @rob-ot I'm pretty sure that you can also disable them because I'm having the checkbox right in front of me. Also, the table has a column called `disable` with a tinyint(4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling a user is not default enabled on the standard user object. I've tackled this issue myself by creating a model extending the FrontendUser from TYPO3 and adding a property disable.

```php
class FrontendUser extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $disable;

    /**
     * Gets the Disable
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getDisable() {
        return (bool)$this->disable;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Disable
     *
     * @param boolean $disable
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDisable($disable) {
        $this->disable = (bool)$disable;
    }
}
```

You might need a bit of typoscript to map it to the proper property

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence{
        classes {
            VendorName\ExtensionName\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                    columns {
                        disable.mapOnProperty = disable
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need the FrontendUserRepository as well

```
/**
* A Frontend User repository
*/
class FrontendUserRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository {
}
```

After this you can use the newly created FrontendUser model as your model for the FrontendUser, inject it, and happily use

```
$userModel->setDisable(1);
// and
$userModel->getDisable();
```

(All namespaces are fully written, this is not necessary obviously, but simply done for ease of reading)

Comment: Let's say that each block of code has a number from 1 to 4. Which block needs to be inserted into which file of my extension? I've got this and it somehow doesn't work: 1 - Model/Dummy.php / 2 - setup.ts / 3 - DummyRepository.php / 4 - DummyController.php

Comment: That seems to be right. What I can think of is maybe a typoscript which is not loaded correctly. Check the typoscript object browser if your mapping is correctly loaded. Otherwise show us your extension code completely. Could be something as simple as a typo in a namespace for instance

Comment: Curious to see if you got it to work Norman? Or is there still a problem with the code?

Comment: Oh, thanks for asking, I totally forgot to answer. Worked great, thanks!